# C# - Get Url from browser

Tags: c#, winforms

So just like uTorrent gets magnet links and opens them,
How can I setup my WinForm app to get a URL from Default Browser (in this case my default is Chrome) and open that URL in EO.WebBrowser within my app?
I don't have any code for this yet, as I don't know where to start.
Is this something that would be assigned as a Registry Key?
I know there are Registry keys for uTorrent to handle Magnet links in **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Magnet\shell\open\command**.

What I have is WhatsApp Web open in EO.WebBrowser, and when I click on a URL starting with **https://web.whatsapp.com** or **https://api.whatsapp.com** it would open that link. The thing is the link should be changed to ***web*.whatsapp.com**, instead of ***api*.whatsapp.com**

Comment: Open the Registry an look for the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.torrent` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Magnet` keys.

Comment: I got it working... well almost. I had to create a URL Protocol for my app. Whenever I open a WhatsApp link inside Chrome, or any other Desktop browser, it opens up my app...GREAT!!!

But how do I get the URL to the WebBrowser control inside my form

Comment: I want this URL as string in my app so that I can append the string from api.whatsapp to web.whatsapp